# Count total if a condition is checked

Tags: google-sheets

I'm wondering how to count a checkbox in a row if a condition is checked, in this case the "Si" in column B, which I translate to "TRUE" in Column D ( would later hide ). It should be fairly easy but can't find a solution.

Everything I tried works only if every single B/D has a Si/True, which is not what I want, I want to count each row that has a checkbox checked that doesn't have a SI ( or that does, since it's the same process )

[image]

[image]

Comment: Microsoft Excel is not Google Sheets. Which of the two are you actually using?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF(JUEVES!B2:B="si"; 1; 0)))
```

or:

```
=SUMPRODDUCT(JUEVES!B2:B="si")
```

---

if those are two conditions (not clear from your question):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF((JUEVES!B2:B="si")*(JUEVES!D2:D=TRUE); 1; 0)))
```